# When to use 'app.params' and 'req.params'?

Tags: node.js, express

Since, I can get parameters from both the methods using a code similar to the one below:

`req.params.<PARAM NAME>` in single/many separate `app.METHOD` function(s)

(think this may result in code repetition)

&

`app.params(<ARRAY>,<CALLBACK>)` function, independent of the `app.METHOD` functions, and called if the URL contains any parameter (:id, :name .etc)

What are the use-cases to apply one over the other?

Comment: One express thing that can help to avoid code repetition is app.param middleware: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be is using `app.params` for parameter validation or some sort of preprocessing. For example the express docs provide and example where you attach `req.user` information to the request using `app.params` and after that you can work directly with the user information instead of processing the parameter again. Using `req.params` would be more specific in terms of processing the specific query. For example I'd use `req.params` for a REST endpoint which should perform an operation by id (update/delete) as in general there shouldn't be any additional preprocessing involder.